# Confusion in definition of associate, unit, monic associate and their use in definition of "irreducible" for polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having some confusion over the concepts of "associate", and "unit" in the context of polynomial rings. This is partly due to the fact that the concept of "irreducible" of polynomials are defined using different terms but end up being equivalent in meaning.  Also, what how to find associates and monic associates in different polynomial rings over $Z_p$ for different $p$.

The concept of "associate", in the case of commutative rings, it is defined as follows:

> Let $F$ denote a field.  
> An element $a$ in a commutative ring with identity $R$ is said to be an $\textit{associate}$ of an element $g$ of $R$ if $a=bu$ for some unit $u$.  In this case $b$ is also an associate of $a$ because $u^{-1}$ is a unit and $b=au^{-1}$.

Question 1:  Am I right to understand that in the case of finite field $Z_p$ where $p$ is not prime, then the associate only comes from units in $Z_p$.  In the case of $p=4, 6, 8$, their associates are respectively, $\{1,3\}$, $\{1,5\}$ and $\{1,3,5,7\}$

In polynomial rings, a polynomial $f(x)\in R[x]$ is a unit in $R[x]$ if and only if $f(x)$ is a constant polynomial that is a unit in $R$. If $F$ is a field,, then the units in $F[x]$ are the nonzero constants in $F$.  The definition of "associate" for polynomial is defiend as:

> $f(x)$ is an associate of $g(x)$ in $F[x]$ if and only if $f(x)=cg(x)$ for some nonzero $c\in F$

Question 2:  For polynomials rings, associates is defined in relation to the polynomial's coefficients, it still make sense to define associates over $Z_p[x]$ where $p$ is not prime.  I asked this because from the following question

"Every nonzero $f(x)\in F[x]$ has a unique monic associate in $F[x]$"

If this statement holds, then finding an associate of a polynomial $f(x)$ can work in every finite field $Z_p$ for all value of $p$.  But for the case of monic associate, it only make sense to talk about a polynomial's monic associate over $Z_p$ only when $p$ is prime.  The reason monic associate is different is because if I am given a polynomial $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}x^{k}\in F[x]$, $f$'s monic associate is $c\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}x^{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}ca_{k}x^{k}\equiv x^{k} + \{\text{sum of terms}\}$ 
, where $c$ and $a_{n}$ are inverse of each other.

As exercises:

monic associate for

$3x^{5}-4x^{2}+1$ in $Z_{7}[x]$ and in $Z_{12}[x]$

$5(3x^{5}-4x^{2}+1)=15x^{5}-20x^{2}+5 \equiv x^{5}-6x^{2}+1$ in $Z_7[x]$ Also, since every element in $Z_7[x]$ are units, we can multiply by any number $c\in Z_p$ to get a different monic associate.

But for $Z_{12}[x]$, the units are $\{1,5,7,11\}$, so there does not exist any monic associate for $3x^{5}-4x^{2}+1$. however if the leading coefficient of a polynomial are $\{1,5,7,11\}$, then it is possible to find a monic associate because they are their own inverses.

For the case of finding associate in $Z_p[x]$, they can be found in cases for all values of $p$.   As examples: 
for $3x^{5}-4x^{2}+1$ in $Z_{5}[x]$, we can multiply this polynomial by any non zero constant congruent some other numbers for its coefficients.  $c(3x^{5}-4x^{2}+1)=c3x^{5}-c4x^{2}+c \equiv a_{5}x^{5}-a_{2}x^{2}+c$ in $Z_7[x]$. Same reasoning applies to the case of $Z_{12}[x]$

Finally for the different definitions of irreducibility.  I got two different definitions.  In the second one below, the term "units' are used.  How is that the same as "associate".  I think there a way to prove that units are also associates.  I am not sure what the correct statement is.

> Let $F$ be a field.  A nonconstant polynomial $p(x)\in F(x)$ is said to be irreducible if its only divisors are its associates and the nonzero constant polynomials (units).  A nonconstant polynomial that is not irreducible is said to be reducible.

> Let $D$ be an integral domain.  A polynomial $f(x)$ from $D[x]$ that is neither the zero polynomial nor a unit in $D[x]$ is said to be $\textit{irreducible over $D$}$ if, whenever $f(x)$ is expressed as a product $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, with $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ from $D[x]$, then $g(x)$ or $h(x)$ is a unit in $D[x]$.  A nonzero non-unit element of $D[x]$ that is not irreducible over $D$ is called $\textit{reducible over $D$}$.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

**Q1:** I don't quite understand what you've said, but if $F$ is a field then every nonzero element is associate to every other nonzero element because they're all units. So the equivalence classes under the equivalence relation "$x$ is associate to $y$" are $0$ and everything else.

**Q2:** I don't quite understand what you've said here either. There's no question mark so I don't know what your question is. If $F$ is a field then every polynomial in $F[x]$ has a unique monic associate; this condition in fact characterizes fields. As you've correctly noticed, $\mathbb{Z}/12$ is not a field.

**Q3:** The two definitions are equivalent. I don't know what you mean by "units are also associates." The grammar of the term "associate" is that it takes as input *two* elements; it's "$x$ is associate to $y$," so it doesn't mean anything to say that $x$ is associate without specifying a $y$ that it's associate to.

To prove $\Rightarrow$ (the first definition implies the second), suppose $f$ is irreducible according to the first definition. If $f(x) = g(x) h(x)$ then $g, h$ are both divisors of $f$, so by hypothesis $g, h$ must be either associates of $f$ or units. If $g$ is an associate of $f$ then $h$ is a unit and if $g$ is a unit then $h$ is an associate of $f$; moreover the same is true with $g$ and $h$ swapped. So at least (in fact exactly) one of $g$ and $h$ is a unit, which means the second definition holds.

To prove $\Leftarrow$ (the second definition implies the second), suppose $f$ is irreducible according to the second definition (and that $D$ is a field). If $g$ is a divisor of $f$, we want to show that it's either a unit or an associate of $f$. We have $f = gh$ for some polynomial $h$, and by hypothesis either $g$ or $h$ is a unit. If $g$ is a unit then we're done and if $h$ is a unit then $g$ is an associate (just like in the previous proof). So the first definition holds.

Comment: thank you for the clarifications. Sorry I am getting back to you so late.  I was away from my computer.
With regards to the first two questions, after seeing your comment, I realised I expressed the definition of associate of polynomials incorrectly.  It has to do with whether the definition of a polynomial $f$ and it's associate $g$ where $f(x)=cg(x)$ for some nonzero $c\in F[x]$, whether $c$ has to be a unit. Another words, does the definition for associate of two polynomials is defined only for fields,..

Comment: but not for arbitrary rings. I understand it makes perfect sense in the case of a polynomial $f$'s monic associate $g$ has to be defined solely for the case of fields.

Comment: @Seth: yes, $c$ has to be a unit (over a field this is equivalent to $c$ being a nonzero constant). If $D$ is an integral domain you can show that the units in $D[x]$ are exactly the units in $D$. This fails if $D$ has nontrivial nilpotents and then there are at least two possible definitions of what an associate of a polynomial in $D[x]$ so you’d have to pick one.

Comment: there are two possible definitions?  My understanding of a polynomial $f$ associate to $g$ for some constant $c\in F$ has to do with polynomial division.  If it is in the case of arbitary ring, is there a proceds of division where the existence of nonzero $c$ is not a unit?  Also can you please tell me what the other definition is and if they are equivalent?  I have not seen anything relating nipotent elements and existence of units?  Also will both have to work only for fields or is it only for one of them?   Thank you again.

Comment: @Seth: as you've quoted in your question, in any commutative ring $R$ two elements $a, b$ are associate if $a = bu$ where $u$ is a unit. If $R = D[x]$ for $D$ an integral domain then the units of $R$ are the units of $D$. But if $D$ has nilpotents then there are more units in $D[x]$ than just the units in $D$ (check that if $n$ is nilpotent then $1 + nx$ is a unit, for example) and so you have to make a decision about whether you want "associate" to refer to units in $D[x]$ or only units in $D$.

Comment: what would be the suble differences between referring to units in $D[x]$ or only units in $D[x]$?  Also the standard definition for associate of one polynomial to another, which context does it usually refer to?

Comment: @Seth: I can't think of a place where this distinction is particularly important off the top of my head. In practice if someone's talking about associates of polynomials then $D$ is probably an integral domain if not a field so the difference doesn't matter.

Comment: @QiaochunYuan is there an advantage when talking about associates of polynomials in the context of integral domains vs fields?  I think this is the issue relating to units you are referring to.  If you don't know, i can look it up tomorrow morning.  I am still new to this stuff.  Probably as i learn more. It will get sorted out in my head eventually.  Thank you again.

Comment: @Seth: I don't understand your question. Is there an advantage to what?

Comment: when you told me the differences doesn't matter, i thought it would be something i will need to know later on in a more advanced context.   I know in abstract algebra, i am finding that there are myriad of minutiae technical details that are associated to a concept as a consequence of a definition.

Comment: @Seth: I strongly recommend not worrying about the case that $D$ isn't an integral domain for now. Just keep going and you'll see what the point of these definitions are (I assume they're leading up to a discussion of unique factorization).

Comment: @QiaochunYuan  Yes, it leads to there then to polynomials in congruemce arithmetic.  The book i am using start things with rings before groups.

Comment: I have another question related to associates, and I thought if i could ask you instead of making another similar post.  So if a polynomial $f$ in a field $F=R[x]$, is an associate of a polynomial $g$ if there exist a unit v where $f=vg$.  With regards to this definition, it really does not matter whether $g$ is irreducible or not?  I mean, as an example:   $2x^4- 4*x^2-16=2(x^2-4)(x^2+2)$, both $(x^2-4)$ and $(x^2+2)$ are associates of $2x^4-4*x^2-16$, even though one is reducible while the other one is not.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Seth: I don't understand your example. $x^2 - 4$ and $x^2 + 2$ aren't units, so this doesn't exhibit them as associates of $2x^4 - 4x^2 - 16$. It doesn't matter whether $g$ is irreducible or not, and $g$ is irreducible iff $f$ is.

Comment: I meant for $2x^4- 4*x^2-16$ its associates are: $2(x^2-4)$ or $2(x^2+2)$, I think from the following definition of irreducible polynomials:
"Let $F$ be a field.  A nonconstant polynomial $p(x)\in F(x)$ is said to be irreducible if its only divisors are its associates and the nonzero constant polynomials (units)", I got the impression that the associate of polynomial f to that of g, where $f=cg$, where c is a unit,  $g$ has to be irreducible.  Basically, $f$ has to factor through to non irreducible polynomials.  Or that is not necessary the case, and all it matters...

Comment: ...if the polynomial g can be multiplied by a unit.

Comment: @Seth: I think you are confused about at least one definition but I’m not sure which. As I already said, $g$ does not need to be irreducible, and your first sentence is incorrect. Please reread the definitions more carefully.

Comment: sorry for my late reply.  I reread a definition and were able to find some exercises associated with the concepts. You are correct, I am misreading the definition.  a polynomial f and its associate has nothing to do whether the associate polynomial is irreducible or not.  I think the way the definition is worded confused me at first.  Thank you again so much for your help.  :)